# Motivation on traces, norms and discriminants

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I am looking for some motivation for the definitions of trace, norm and discriminant (in the context of finite field extensions). For example (but not limited to) any interesting theorems proved using techniques involving the mentioned above, or intuition on why and how they were defined in the first place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the motivation, at least for the trace and the norm, is that they are functions from what you want to study (the number field) to what you already know about (the rationals), and thus they may enable you to reduce questions you can't immediately answer to ones that you can. Just to give one tiny example, to prove $\alpha=1+\sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible in the ring $\{{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b{\rm\ in\ }{\bf Z}\}}$ of integers of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, you may assume $\alpha=\beta\gamma$, and take norms: $6=N(\beta)N(\gamma)$. Since the equations $a^2+5b^2=2$ and $a^2+5b^2=3$ have no integer solutions, you must have $N(\beta)=1$ or $N(\gamma)=1$, from which you deduce that one of the numbers $\beta,\gamma$ is a unit, so $\alpha$ is irreducible.

Comment: Along the same lines: multiplication by $\alpha$ is $\mathbf{Q}$-linear map of $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, and so it has a matrix with respect to any basis, including say $\{1,\sqrt{-5}\}$, in which $$\alpha = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -5 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right).$$ The trace (2) of that matrix is the trace of $\alpha$, and the determinant (6) of the matrix is the norm of $\alpha$. Finding good bases for number theory is one application of the discriminant.